# Can I replicate programmatically what a tap on the UIStatusBar does w/ UISearchController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I can't find a way to scroll a `UIScrollView` to the top in the same way the `UIStatusBar` does when the `UINavigationItem` contains a `UISearchController`. In that case, the scroll view scrolls to the top *including* showing the search bar. If I try to do this with the usual suspects (calling scroll, setting the content offset, etc.), I can't seem to make the search bar appearing.

Can I replicate programmatically what a tap on the `UIStatusBar` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I think Apple uses private API here to make it. But if you want to replicate something look like it, make the search bar appearing. You can follow step:

- Scroll `UIScrollView` to top

  ```
  self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
  ```
- After that, show search bar and large title

  ```
  // Show large title
  self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
  // Show search bar
  self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeAlways;
  ```
- When search bar and large title are displayed, reset `navigationItem` properties to give `scrollView` normal behavior

  ```
  self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = YES;
  self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeAutomatic;
  ```

Result:

[image: enter link description here]

Working code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
  self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeAlways;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = YES;
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeAutomatic;
  }];
}];
```

For more detail, you can take a look at [my demo repo](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/touching-status-bar-effect).

Comment: Amazing, that does it! Thanks for the demo program. There is a tiny bit of flicker when the `UISearchBarController` reappears, but that's probably the best we can do with public APIs. Congratulations!

Comment: I should give answer sooner. I had intended to answer your question 2 days ago but I didn't because of that flicker. Finally, do it without receiving down vote. Thank you ;)